# Read information of the German EC/Giro Card through NFC in Android

Tags: java, android, kotlin, nfc, bank

Does anybody know a way on how to read the data of a German Giro Card/EC Card through NFC? 
I have been trying it with EMV Card Readers, and somehow the succeed on reading the Card Number, but aren't able to read the bank Identification Code (BIC) / SWIFT.

It would help me a lot since by combining the Card Number and BIC i can generate the IBAN.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you able to retrieve the 19 digit PAN (primary account number)?

If so, digits 4 to 8 are the 5 digit short bank identification number, and digits 9 to 18 are the account number. Digits 1-3 are a prefix, and digit 19 is a luhn check digit.

A list of short bank identification numbers and corresponding SWIFT BICs can be found at Deutsche Bundesbank: https://www.bundesbank.de/de/aufgaben/unbarer-zahlungsverkehr/serviceangebot/bankleitzahlen/download---bankleitzahlen-602592